# Node Js - $addToSet nor $push don't work in update with Mongoose (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with Mongoose and I want to update a document in MongoDB using the module mongoose, this is my schema:

```
    var User = new mongoose.Schema({

        name: String,
        email: String,
        list_houses: [{
            id_house: String,
            price: Double
        }],
        ...

    });
```

When I want to add a value 'id_house' without repeating using the code below, this it does not work

```
User.update({'name': Name}, 
{$addToSet: {'list_houses': { 'id_house': new_houses , 'price': new_prices } } } ,
    if(err)console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
});
```

When I execute this, the result in BD is:

```
>db.users.find().pretty()
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : qweqweqweqweqweqwe,
    "email" : adadasdweqwe@gmail.com,
    "name" : Richard Smith,
    "list_houses" : [ ],
    .....
}
```

I used $push too, but neither it works, I don't know what is the problem with my code now.

Comment: Couple of things. You don't have `name` field in the collection that you find and so no update occurs. Other thing you are using incorrect label `id_houses` vs `id_house` for embedded docs

Comment: Thank you man! It was an example, but do you know how to solve my problem?

Comment: in place of callback you have directly written two lines. That might be causing problems. Are you using the same exact code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you but `$addToSet` doesn`t work with Object values in the array.

You ask me why? 
Logic is simple, In JS when you compare strings/number etc with same values you do get a `true` but not with Object

So `{a:1}` is not equal to `{a:1}`. Of course because Objects are compared with reference.

Now the solution to your problem is you'll have to do it manually

get the list using find. Check in the list if your object exists. If not add to the list.

You can also specify your object details within find query and just find may be the documents not with this data(to be inserted) in it

Comment: if that is  the case, then `$push` should have worked, But according to OP `$push` doesn't work either.

Comment: $addToSet compares. $push doesnt even compare and inserts in the array. I think thats the exact issue OP has